# edit link from google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

While I get a file object from google drive api, I want to get the link to edit this file with google docs interface.

But as defined [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource), I only get the link to google docs if the drive.apps.readonly scope is set to readonly.

Is there any way to get this link for editing?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I only get the link to google docs if the drive.apps.readonly scope is set to readonly"?

Comment: I may be wrong but it is what I read in the documentation

Comment: Can you paste the specific part of the documentation you are referring to into the question

Comment: It is linked in the main message

Comment: Up to you. If you paste the specifics of your problem, we can help. If not, you're on your own. As it stands your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually use drive.apps.readonly scope. "readonly" means that you cannot edit installed google apps, but you still can get list of these apps, and open any document for editing.